# How do lambdas work in Scala, are they functions on top of anonymous classes?

Tags: scala, lambda

The title might be a little confusing so let me elaborate, I've been reading some criticism regarding Scala. It was an email sent to Tyepsafe regarding some deficiencies in Scala from [Coda Hale (Yammer's Infrastructure Architect)](http://codahale.com/downloads/email-to-donald.txt), so to quote:

> we stopped seeing lambdas as free and started seeing them as syntactic sugar on top of anonymous classes and thus acquired the same distaste for them as we did anonymous classes.

So, from this, I have a couple of questions regarding how lambdas work in Scala:

- What is the difference between a free function and a function that is bound to an anonymous class (technically, aren't all functions bound to the `main` singleton object)?
- What is the impact on performance of using an anonymous class bound function instead of a free function?

Comment: Who cares how lambdas are implemented?

Comment: Yeah, it's not clear I understand the objection there.  A closure needs to capture state *somehow*, and an anonymous class seems as good a way as any to do so.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Exactly, but what could be a potential problem. I mean, are there side-effects _because_ of this? I think this, and I tell myself, Yammer is looking for a java replacement, they don't care about functional purity.

Comment: By syntactic sugar does he mean that any use of anonymous functions can be transformed into an OOP solution?  Because under that criteria every programming language is just syntactic sugar for a Turing Machine.

Comment: @HahaHortness I don't think that is the main concern. I just fail to see how an anonymous class is bad. Does it add more memory usage?

Comment: I think one of the main points there is that in Scala's `for` comprehensions (which are syntactic sugar for a `map` or `foreach` + a lambda), the lambda body is not "free" like the body of a traditional `for` loop in Java. I've seen as much as a 25% speedup in my own Scala code when substituting a `while` loop for an existing `for` expression. Similarly, any other control construct using higher-order functions (e.g. `fold`, `reduce`, `find`...) can't be viewed as "free" compared to a traditional loop-based solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, lambdas are still objects, instances of anonymous classes.

This is how the JVM works, **all** references are objects.  You can have either references or values (primitives) and there's no way around it.

Later versions of Java have MethodHandles.  But it's worth noting that `MethodHandle` is *also* still just an abstract class - albeit one that the JVM specifically knows how to optimise away at runtime.

Also also worth noting is that the JVM can often perform escape analysis on abstract classes (such as Scala's functions), and optimise these away too.

On top of this, Scala can use *any* object with an `apply` method as though it were a `Function`.  In this case, the explicit call to `apply` is emitted in the bytecode and you're not dealing with anonymous classes any more.

Given all of the above, it's impossible to make a general statement regarding the performance of Scala's function implementation, it depends on your specific code/use case.  In general, I wouldn't worry unless you hit a corner case where your profiler pinpoints a problem here (which is *very* unlikely)

Comment: Yes, but how are free functions that different from functions strapped onto anonymous objects?

Comment: On the bare metal, a free function is just a pointer to where its code starts.  When wrapped in a object you have a pointer to the object from where you must locate the pointer to the function in its vtable.  In a managed language you have a pointer to the pointer to the object, allowing it to be moved during garbage collection.  A lot of this can be optimised away by a good JIT though.

Comment: So what you're saying is that a function stuck onto an anonymous class  won't add much of a load at runtime?

Comment: No much. The bigger cost is that for loops and while loops keep the code inline and can work directly on primitives.  With lamdas you incur a boxing cost, this will go away with future versions of Scala and JVM improvements.  This cost is not specifically down to free functions vs. anonymous classes though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in C for example a function is just a 32 or 64 bit pointer to a place in memory to jump to and the concept of a closure doesn't really apply since you can't declare an anonymous c function.  I don't know how the C++ lambdas work, I guess the compiler makes a method and passes the fields you want in the closure along with parameters.  Maybe that's what you're looking for.  In the JVM you have to wrap your logic in a class so now you have a virtual table of methods, fields, and some methods related to synchronization and the type system.

What is the impact on performance?...I don't know, have you noticed an impact on performance?  A lot of that extra Java stuff I described really isn't needed for an anonymous class and might just get optimized out.  I imagine there are butterflies that influence the weather more than the extra JVM stuff would effect your software.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: OK, but a function in C is not a closure.